# iPad Safari tabbed layout in iOS7

Tags: mobile-safari, ios7

I updated iOS7 in my iPad3. However I noted that safari shows normal tabs like earlier and it doesn't show the new tabbed layout feature. Anybody knows how to activate? Or this feature is only for the iPhone safari? Please clarify.

Comment: I thought SO was for programming questions? http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

Safari on iPad shows a rows of tabs across the top like before. The new 3D tab appearance is on iPhone only.